# We are facing this error in header unable to understand the issue

Tags: customization, headers, wp-head

> call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'add_search_form' not found or invalid function name in /home2/zeonu81d/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php

Please help

Comment: Like the error says, `add_search_form()` isn't a function. If you are trying to place a search form use `get_search_form()` instead.

Comment: Can you suggest how to do it

Comment: Somewhere in your code you have `add_action( <something>, 'add_search_form' );` or `add_filter( <something>, 'add_search_form' );`. You need to find that line of code and work out what it was trying to do, because as Abhik says the add_search_form function doesn't exist and you have a hook trying to call it. Search all of your files - WordPress core, plugins and themes - for 'add_search_form' e.g. using grep.

Comment: not working I have tried

Comment: Show us the code where you are suspecting the error is coning from.

Comment: if ( 0 == $the_['accepted_args'] ) {
     $value = call_user_func( $the_['function'] );
    } elseif ( $the_['accepted_args'] >= $num_args ) {
     $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], $args );
    } else {
     $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], array_slice( $args, 0, (int) $the_['accepted_args'] ) );
    }
   }
  } while ( false !== next( $this->iterations[ $nesting_level ] ) );

  unset( $this->iterations[ $nesting_level ] );
  unset( $this->current_priority[ $nesting_level ] );

  $this->nesting_level--;

  return $value;
 } this is the code

Comment: That's the core WordPress code that's throwing the error, but the error is caused by other code. Code that you likely added. Have you been adding code about a search form recently? What's that code (include it in your question, not a comment).

Comment: that an ivory search plugin, since i have added this its showing error, now its after deactivating it error is not going

Comment: Solved in funtion.php theme file deleted the function add_search_form'